# Raise compile error if braces not closed at end of file (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Is there a way to raise a warning or error if the C++ compiler comes to the end of file without all braces being closed? We never use headers which spill a scope into another file and would like to receive compiler warnings if it happens by accident. Compiler MSVC 2010, but others might be of interest too.

```
// Utilities.hpp
namespace example
{

class Utilities
{
}

//<EOF> -> should warn or error
```

Edit: I am willing to put a marker/pragma/Macro at the end of each file, where I know the brace level should be 0.

Comment: Interesting question. I do not know the answer but if you did not find on ,you can build a small tool that count { and } and ensure that they are the same. if you have an auto build tool like Jenkins , you may work around and add it to Jenkins. I know this is not what you are looking for but just something came to my mind if you did not find a real solution

Comment: If you've got a tool like Jenkins, just call the compiler on the header file (!)

Comment: Nice idea with Jenkins, but I want it mostly during development when writing unity builds. There a runaway can be hard to track down if 50 cpp files are concated.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable method is

```
#define AT_GLOBAL_SCOPE namespace { }
```

because that can only appear at global *or namespace* scope. So it unfortunately won't catch that missing } from another namespace, but it will catch the class-case, as well as missing parentheses and semicolons.

Comment: Could we catch namespace runaway by something like: `int test;
namespace eofguard
{
  int testB = ::test;
}`? Would need a unique name for test per file though...

Answer (score 1):

In principle, this isn't known by the compiler proper - the preprocessor is sufficiently separate from the compiler proper that different files are "not known", it's just one long stream of source-code as far as the compiler is concerned.

One of the problems here is that the "understanding of the source code" is different at different levels. The preprocessor which inserts the `#include ...` into the source stream doesn't really know anything about `{` and `}` in other ways than "they are not alphanumeric" [which affects how macros and such are handled]. And consider that you could have [even if it's perhaps a bad idea]:

```
 #define START {
 #define END }

 start
   ... 
   ...
 end
```

(The C preprocessor CAN be used for other things than C-code, so it's not "meant" to understand the language it is compiling)

I guess you could write a small tool that parses code and just counts up for `{` and down for `}`, and check for equality [you have to care for quotes and comments, but everything else should be counted]. But of course, the compiler will eventually tell you in some way, so I'm not sure that's much use. That assumes that there are no uneven sets of braces in macros.

Comment: Even if the compiler does not know about EOF, could it know that a brace is open a certain point (#Pragma?)?

Comment: The problem isn't about knowing EOF, it is about knowing where a particular include-file starts and ends, and from the part of the compiler that understands C or C++, that information is not available. In an integrated compiler with preprocessor included (like clang and gcc at least), it would in theory be possible, but there's all manner of difficulties - and would it really be worth all the effort....

Comment: Mats: I mean, I could tell the compiler that this is the end of a include-file by putting a marker/macro/pragma there, so the compiler could know.